# Python 3.7 unrecognizable characters of sys.executable

Tags: python-3.7

**Why the value of sys.executable is unrecognizable?**

when I use python3.7 to create venv,I got an error:

```
python -m venv venv
Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ŘE'
```

then I add `print()` to `__init__.py` of `venv` and finally found that the value of `sys.executable is wrong`. But `sys.getdefaultencoding()` prints "utf-8".

I was confused and try to use python3.6 to found difference. But in python 3.6, all works well.

please help me to find the reason and correction.
 Thanks

Comment: I reinstall python37,it' dose't work.And I add 
`sys.executable = r"C:\Software\Python\Python37\python.exe"`
to `__main__.py` which in venv dir ,it works normally.

Comment: i find the reason!A few days ago,to fix an another error,i download a `api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll` from internet and add it into my system32.So just remove it